# Changing programmatic/VFL constraints on-the-fly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm manually adding a subview to a view and am positioning it with constraints...

```
UIView *superview = self.view;
UIView *subview = self.subview;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(superview, subview);

[self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[subview]-(0)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(0)-[subview]-(0)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

This positions my subview neatly in the superview. However, at a later time I would like to apply a margin around my subview (with animation) so that it is inset by 100. So in effect, my constraints in visual format language would be...

```
"H:|-(100)-[subview]-(100)-|"
"V:|-(100)-[subview]-(100)-|"
```

How can I attach variables to my 'margin' value so that I can transition between the two types of display for the subview?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only change the constant value or the priority of a constraint. To change a spacing, you would have to remove the old constraint, remake new ones, and then add them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(0)-[subview]-(0)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]
```

Will return an array with the constraints in the same order that they were specified, you can look for it inside the array and then change its constant value.

But I think the easiest way is to create a reference to it like so (you can store it in an internal variable or property):

```
NSLayoutConstraint* space = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.button2
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:12.0];
```

and add it like this:

```
[self.view addConstraints:@[space]];
```

then you can change space.constant to some value. and animate it like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
 // Make all constraint changes here
 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];}];
```

Other approach would be to remove all constraints and add VFL constraints with updated values, and then perform layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block as above.

Comment: Thanks. Worked a treat!